# Calculating TCP total length

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a Python code which calculates TCP checksum as described in http://www.roman10.net/2011/11/27/how-to-calculate-iptcpudp-checksumpart-1-theory/

So, I need to calculate the TCP length both for the pseudo header, and in order to get the relevant TCP data bytes from the frame buffer.

So I tried `TCP length = Frame size - TCP offset - 4` where the 4 should be the size of the Ethernet CRC.

This works fine, for some packets, but then I got some packets which do not have Ethernet CRC. So my question is, how can I tell TCP length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start with the frame size, but rather the IP size from the IP header.  You can't know whether a particular interface will let you see the Ethernet FCS.